# quasi diagonal matrix transformation

Tags: diagonalization

I need a help please when I have a matrix with complex eigenvalues for example $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1& 0\\0 &0 &1\\-24 &-29 &-18\end{pmatrix}$$ with its eigenvalues of: $-16.3$, $-0.844+0.871j$, and $-0.844-0.871j$

Matrix $A$ can be diagonalized to the classical known form of $$A_\text{diag}=\begin{pmatrix}-0.844+0.871j& 0& 0\\0 &-0.844-0.871j& 0\\0 &0 &-16.3\end{pmatrix}$$ with a vandermone transformation matrix

The Question is I need a transformation matrix to transform matrix $A$ to the form of matrix $A_d$ (with no complex elements) $$A_d=\begin{pmatrix}-0.844 &0.871& 0\\-0.871 &-0.844& 0\\0 &0 &-16.3\end{pmatrix}$$ and this form called a quasi-diagonal matrix

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{2} \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 -i & 1 \\
 1& -i 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 i &1 \\
 1& i
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1&0 \\
 0&1 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\frac{1}{2} \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 -i & 1 \\
 1& -i 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a + b i&0 \\
 0&a - bi 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 i &1 \\
 1& i
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 a&b \\
 -b&a 
\end{array}
\right)
$$